# Disable the strict password prompt focus on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, network-manager, password, vpn

I am using a VPN connection to connect to my work network. Whenever I connect I have to input my password and TOTP token. I have set up the connection within the default network manager GUI in Ubuntu 22.04 as it is an OpenVPN-based VPN.

When I try to connect to the VPN I get prompted for the password and TOTP as expected. What I find annoying is that I cannot use the rest of the system while the prompt is displayed on the screen, which can be annoying as I cannot access my Bitwarden repository and/or Authy to copy my TOTP token.

[image: VPN password prompt]

Is this something that can be disabled as a behavior or is it hard-wired into the system?

Answer (score -1):

Updating my answer based on the comment.

```
nmcli connection modify <your-connection-name> vpn.secrets password <your-vpn-password>
```

save everything

```
nmcli connection up <your-connection-name>
```

**Note**: Using this way can be risky in case others have access to your terminal history

Comment: I do not want to remove the password prompt, just make it so that the desktop in the background is accessible while the prompt is raised, so I can access the TOTP generator, that is all. I do not find this essential, but it is an annoyance that I could do without. Also the password that is being requested is not the system password, but rather the VPN network password.

Comment: Updated my answer. This should work